# Swagger UI Editor to generate.yaml

Tags: swagger

There are many tools for Swagger yaml file editing . But with all of them I found, we have to edit the yaml files and we only can see the output. I want to know any editor which those yaml are generated according to a UI application where we can visually design. (for example, dreamweaver, it allows the user to design visually, meanwhile it generates all the html for us).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any graphic user interface for Swagger editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165623/is-there-any-graphic-user-interface-for-swagger-editor)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for: https://studio.restlet.com
(There is a free plan for personal use)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.