# Is there tool that can be used to Visually design Swagger REST APIs and then generate the Swagger Specification YAML specification?

Tags: rest, editor, swagger, development-environment

These days everyone is making REST applications. So far i used only swagger editor for generating those files.

Does anyone know if there is good mature tool or IDE that thave ability to visually design  Swagger REST APIs and then generate the Swagger Specification YAML specification file?

Tool can be commercial or opensource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger UI Editor to generate.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42549325/113116)

Answer (score 1):

I am using https://studio.restlet.com for that.

It is a great tool and it is pretty in intuitive..
You can do export/import from Swagger and RAML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using postman for testing api. Postman collections can be exported and transformed to valid Swagger 2.0 YAML on https://apimatic.io/transformer.

Exported YAML file then import on swaggerhub https://app.swaggerhub.com were changes can be made if needed.

Folders from postman are transformed into tags, request models are generated by body of request and response examples can be used to document different error responses.