# Translating HTML input values to a Swagger/OpenAPI spec file

Tags: html, swagger, openapi

I know there are multiple ways of converting a Swagger spec file into an HTML file but I was wondering if there is a way to do it the other way around? Say you have a couple of HTML input boxes like so:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="text" name="version">
```

And once you type in values, it would result in something like:

```
"info": {
  "title": "ABC",
  "version": "1.0.0"
```

Basically creating a Swagger/OpenAPI spec file via HTML input.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to convert an API Explorer web console page of some type?

Comment: @Grokify I'm trying to take input from a web page and dynamically create a spec file from it based on the values entered.

Comment: Like a GUI editor for OpenAPI/Swagger? There are a few already out there.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Is there tool that can be used to Visually design Swagger REST APIs and then generate the Swagger Specification YAML specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644563/is-there-tool-that-can-be-used-to-visually-design-swagger-rest-apis-and-then-gen)